# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quartz'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to work on python3 and using mac. I have installed pyobjc-core and pyobjc, but the error said `Quartz` not found. I'm very new to this kind of installing. Is there any solution?

Here is my error from pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Thyme/PycharmProjects/DinosourBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 5, in <module>
    import Quartz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quartz'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Thyme/PycharmProjects/DinosourBot/Bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Users/Thyme/PycharmProjects/DinosourBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_osx as platformModule
  File "/Users/Thyme/PycharmProjects/DinosourBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py", line 7, in <module>
    assert False, "You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"
AssertionError: You must first install pyobjc-core and pyobjc: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: did u try `pip install quartz`?

Comment: I use pip3 install quartz but it didnt work.

Comment: I have solved the problem by install pyobic-framework-quartz, it provide by pycharm

Comment: If you solved the problem, add it as an answer so that you can mark the question as Answered and people with similar problems don't have to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by 
installing pyobjc-framework-Quartz, 
it's provided by pycharm

Comment: Actually, my version of pycharm seems to fail; it says it cannot find 'Quartz' by itself. ```source /Users/_USR_/self/timelapse-maker/venv/bin/activate;
pip install Quartz```. I had to use this command instead: `pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
`

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone stumbles here use:

```
pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest it's best to install all of pyObjC, rather than just specific frameworks. Invariably, if you're working with Quartz, you're going to need various CoreFoundation objects and constants at the very least. To say nothing of AppKit, or other frameworks, depending on what you're doing.

`pip install pyobjc` (or `pip3`) should install everything and let you `import Quartz`. (It works for me on several pythons!)